# XML UTF-8 not encoding correctly?

Tags: xml, encoding, utf-8, rider

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIy8v.png)

Trying to open up the plist file in Rider results in this. I've also tried it with texteditor.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zsNy.png)

i want to write the manypoint, position, and simplepoint into a int of -1 but i can only change it using something like this

`defaults write com.ruanniu.ianygo simplepoint 99999`

it however the 99999 is a string instead of an int, hence why I want to use a text editor, but the UTF-8 just seems to be a bunch of jumbles.

is there any solution to this?

I tried:

`defaults write com.ruanniu.ianygo simplepoint 99999`

I tried to use Rider

Comment: Open file with Notepad.  The do SaveAs and check the encoding in the dialog box.  I suspect the encoding is not UTF-8.  Save file with UTF-8 encoding and try again.

Comment: Please [*do not* use (sole) images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3439404) in your [mcve].
Copy the actual text, paste it into the question, then format it as code. Post a hexadecimal dump in case of (partially) binary content.
          **BTW**, `PLIST` files can be saved in a text or a **binary** format. The text-based documents can be edited with a text editor. However, **you typically should not edit `PLIST` files**, since they are modified by their respective programs as needed.